# How to show generated SQL / raw SQL in TypeORM queryBuilder

Tags: sql, typeorm

I developed `typeorm` `querybuilder`. For the purpose of debugging, I'd like to show the generated SQL query.

I tested `printSql()` method, but it didn't show any SQL query.

```
const Result = await this.attendanceRepository
  .createQueryBuilder("attendance")
  .innerJoin("attendance.child", "child")
  .select(["attendance.childId","child.class","CONCAT(child.firstName, child.lastName)"])
  .where("attendance.id= :id", { id: id })
  .printSql()
  .getOne()

console.log(Result);
```

It returned the following:

```
Attendance { childId: 4, child: Child { class: 'S' } }
```

My desired result is to get the generated SQL query.

Is there any wrong point? Is there any good way to get the SQL query?

Comment: try getQuery(); instead of getOne();

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`.getQuery()` or `.getSql()`

```js
const sql1 = await this.attendanceRepository
    .createQueryBuilder("attendance")
    .innerJoin("attendance.child", "child")
    .select(["attendance.childId","child.class","CONCAT(child.firstName, child.lastName)"])
    .where("attendance.id= :id", { id: id })
    .getQuery();
console.log(sql1);
```

```js
const sql2 = await this.attendanceRepository
    .createQueryBuilder("attendance")
    .innerJoin("attendance.child", "child")
    .select(["attendance.childId","child.class","CONCAT(child.firstName, child.lastName)"])
    .where("attendance.id= :id", { id: id })
    .getSql();
console.log(sql2);
```

Comment: and what about the other functions like `repo.find()`??

Comment: @MuhammadAwais for those there isn't a given method to retrieve the generated SQL, if it's just for debugging purposes you can enable `logging: true` in your DataSource options, which will log any query made to the database

Answer (score 12):

`printSql` can also be used, but it will only print when `logging` is enabled.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      ...options
      logging: true
    }),
  ],
})

await this.attendanceRepository
    .createQueryBuilder("attendance")
    .innerJoin("attendance.child", "child")
    .select(["attendance.childId","child.class","CONCAT(child.firstName, child.lastName)"])
    .where("attendance.id= :id", { id: id })
    .printSql();
```