# addSelect won't select fields in TypeORM

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I'm just trying to select a few columns and typeorm won't let me do this. I have a table called `users` which is represented by the `UserEntity` class.

I'm making the following request:

```
await entityManager.getRepository(UserEntity)
                   .createQueryBuilder(EDBTableNames.USERS)
                   .select(`${EDBTableNames.USERS}.id`)
                   .addSelect(`${EDBTableNames.USERS}.role_name`)
                   .where(`${EDBTableNames.USERS}.role_name IN ('FIGHTER');`)
                   .getMany();
```

The object I get contains the user id only, it doesn't have the corresponding `role_name`. The question is why?

EDIT:

Here's what the `id` and `roleName` fields look like in `UserEntity`:

```
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
    private id: number;

    @Column({
        type: 'enum',
        name: 'role_name',
        enum: EUserRoleName,
    })
    private roleName: EUserRoleName;
```

Comment: what if you use `.select([\`${EDBTableNames.USERS}.id\`, \`${EDBTableNames.USERS}.role_name\`])`? Also I think that `.role_name` should be the name of the `UserEntity`'s property, not the column name, but I'm not sure

Comment: @MicaelLevi Interesting, lemme check it out.

Comment: Nah, no success. `Error: column users.roleName does not exist`, as for passing an array, it didn't work either =(

Comment: @MicaelLevi I don't know how much important it is but `role_name` is an enum. I don't know if it matters, but just in case.

Comment: show us the query result of both your version and with the `.select([])` one

Comment: @MicaelLevi If I pass an array here's what I get: `UserEntity { id: 7 }`. My versions result in the same output. But I've just discovered that if I do `getRawMany` instead of `getMany` the `role_name` is present, but it's no longer an entity obj: `{ users_id: 7, roleName: 'FIGHTER' }`. Seems like there's some issue with the deserialization?

Comment: may be. Have you tried to select non-enum columns? I'm using `.select` passing an array of strings and it works as expected but I never tried with `ENUM` types

Comment: @MicaelLevi no, but I've just given it a try and no, all the same. But again, when I used `getRawMany` all the fields were there...I can't wrap my head around it...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the exact answer but not enough reputation to comment.

Your code seems fine and it should not matter that the field is an enum. You didn't mentioned, if you use a custom naming strategy or use the default TypeORM naming strategy. The strategy takes care of renaming the fields from the model to the desired naming format for the database (e.g. snake case, camel case, custom). Usually, you would need to provide the column name of the model and TypeORM would rename it internally to create the query. Except for raw queries, where you need to use the names as they are used in the database.

Not sure if you are aware that you can have the generated queries being logged to your console. This way you can check the query that TypeORM is generating from your code.

This is how you can globally enable the query logging:

```
export = <PostgresConnectionOptions>{
  type: 'postgres',

  url: process.env.DB_URL,
  schema: process.env.DB_SCHEMA,
  ...

  logger: 'debug', // log queries to console
};
```

Until now, I only used this setting. But in this config you have these two options to customize the logging:

```
/**
 * export declare type LoggerOptions = boolean | "all" | ("query" | "schema" | "error" | "warn" | "info" | "log" | "migration")[];
 */
readonly logging?: LoggerOptions; 
/**
 * Logger instance used to log queries and events in the ORM.
 */
readonly logger?: "advanced-console" | "simple-console" | "file" | "debug" | Logger;
```

Apart from that, you can enable query logging for a specific query: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64413684/11964644